# Indirect recursion for number of nodes in BST is less than a given value

Tags: python, python-3.x

for this case, it ask me to do a indirect recursion. for "def count_less" function. which mean count the number of nodes which is less than the given value.For my code I will have attributeError. Can anyone help me to check my code?

```
class BST:
    """A Binary Search Tree."""

    def __init__(self, container=[]):
        """(BST, list) -> NoneType
        Initialize this BST by inserting the items from container (default [])
        one by one, in the order given.
        """
        # Initialize empty tree.
        self.root = None
        # Insert every item from container.
        for item in container:
            self.insert(item)

    def __str__(self):
        """(BST) -> str
        Return a "sideways" representation of the values in this BST, with
        right subtrees above nodes above left subtrees and each value preceded
        by a number of TAB characters equal to its depth.
        """
        if self.root:
            return self.root._str("")
        else:
            return ""
    def count_less(self, item):
        """(BST, object) -> int
        Return the number of items in this BST that are strictly less than
        item.
        """
        if self.root:
            return self.root.count_less(item)
        else:
            return 0
```

I need to write the function body in this "_BSTNode" class, and call the class method in above "BST" class.

```
class _BSTNode:
    """A node in a BST."""

    def __init__(self, item, left=None, right=None):
        """(_BSTNode, object, _BSTNode, _BSTNode) -> NoneType
        Initialize this node to store item and have children left and right.
        """
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def _str(self, indent):
        """(_BSTNode, str) -> str
        Return a "sideways" representation of the values in the BST rooted at
        this node, with right subtrees above nodes above left subtrees and each
        value preceded by a number of TAB characters equal to its depth, plus
        indent.
        """
        if self.right:
            right_str = self.right._str(indent + "\t")
        else:
            right_str = ""
        if self.left:
            left_str = self.left._str(indent + "\t")
        else:
            left_str = ""
        return right_str + indent + str(self.item) + "\n" + left_str

    def count_less(self: '_BSTNode', item: object) -> int:
        """
        Return the number of items in the BST rooted at this node that are
        strictly less than item.
        """
        if not self.item:
            return 0
        elif item <= self.item:
            if self.left:
                return 1 + self.left.count_less(item)
            return 0
        elif self.item < item:
            if self.left and self.right:
                return 1 + self.left.count_less(item) + self.right.count_less(item)
            elif self.left and not self.right:
                return 1 + self.left.count_less(item)
            elif self.right and not self.left:
                return 1 + self.right.count_less(item)
            else:
                return 1
```

And this is my example I put in and error in my output.

```
    >>> t = BST(container=[5,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9])
    >>> t.count_less(10)
```

Comment: `count_less` is a method of the nodes, you should be calling it using syntax like `self.right.count_less(item)`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Hello thank you for helping me out. I just upated what you told my in my post. But in this case I will have a NonetypeError. Do you know y? Please check my post for the update code

Comment: That's happening because `self.right` or `self.left` is `None`.

Comment: Ok, the initial value for self.right and self.left is None, but I assign them with a number in my example  so they shouldn't be None isn't it?

Comment: Your `BST` isn't infinite, so at some point there's a Node that doesn't have children.  The `left` and `right` of all such nodes will be `None`

Comment: Oh, that is true. So what code I need to add in my code so the code will check when self.right or self.left is None then the code will not execute? I tried isinstance(self.left/right, None) but the system said that the arg2 should be a type

Answer (score 1):

You can depend on the falsy nature of `None` and use `if` statements to check to see if the child nodes exist.  I'm pretty sure that the below code won't return the correct answer: what happens if `self.item == item`? It's possible for the children of both the left and right children to have items that are less than the `item` argument.

```
elif item < self.item:
    if self.left:
        return 1 + self.left.count_less(item)
    return 1
elif item > self.item:
    if self.right:
        return 1 + self.right.count_less(item)
    return 1
```

Comment: you are correct. Is there any way I can count left and right side when they are both less than a given value?

Comment: Hi, I just updated my code and it seems working. But someone told me that there is a better way to code it. What do you think I can do to make it better?